# NSWorkspace openURL not opening files stored in iCloud Drive with default app for file type

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsworkspace, osx-elcapitan, icloud-drive

In my app I use the following code to tell Mac OS X to open a file at a specified URL:

`[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:fileURL];`

Where `fileURL` is a URL to a file stored in my app's iCloud Drive container folder.

In El Capitan, it seems that when a file is placed inside an app's iCloud Drive container, the owner of that file changes to the app who owns that iCloud Drive container.

In my situation, it means that my own app is being asked to open up any file type for files that are stored in my app's iCloud Drive container. If you take the same file and move it to your desktop, the original default app correctly launches.

Has anyone else seen this new behaviour of El Capitan?

I have filed a radar for it: [rdar://22213595](http://rdar://22213595)

Hopefully someone has found a workaround for this. It presents a problem for any app which uses NSWorkspace's openURL command if the file is stored in iCloud Drive. Just because I link to a file from my app, doesn't mean that my app should be responsible for opening it. iTunes should open music files, Preview should open PDFs and Excel should open .xlsx files for example, unless the user has specified otherwise of course.

It shouldn't matter where on someone's drive the file resides to determine which app to use to open it with.

Comment: my App now has the same issue with 10.11 I have filed a technical request with Apple. I have no idea how to solve the issue.

Comment: Please respond back here if you are given a solution by Apple for this problem. I know that my customers are going to start asking me about it soon now that El Capitan is out.

Answer (score 2):

This is the current status from Apple:

"Our iCloud team mentioned that it was an intentional change in El Capitan, but I am still checking with them the logics on the back  and if there is anyway to change that behaivor. I’d update to you once getting their response."